# Someone write Pygments for Mathematica?

Tags: python

Pygments is a python program which highlights source code.
See http://pygments.org/languages/.

Mathematica is not in the list. Is anyone
interested in doing this?

Comment: It's a pity that it is not incorporated into the main Pygments package though ...

Comment: Mathematica is implemented. It is not listed as a language in the list of languages, but is accessible via the demo.

Comment: Yes, but it's of a rather bad quality.  You may not find it usable. I mean that it's a pity that the one I linked to isn't in main Pygments.